# Placing hidden attribute with react in tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to place "hidden" attribute with React.
This is what i tried.
It is supposed to sets/remove hidden attribute based on width:

```js
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1  hidden={(window.innerWidth < 1024) ? "hidden" : ''}>Hello</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need custom attribute - you have to use

```
data-attribute={(window.innerWidth < 1024) ? 'hidden' : ''}
```

If you need set `hidden="hidden"` - you have to use

```
hidden={(window.innerWidth < 1024) ? 'hidden' : ''}
```

In result you must have something like this:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1
      data-attribute={(window.innerWidth < 1024) ? 'hidden' : ''}
      hidden={(window.innerWidth < 1024) ? 'hidden' : ''}
    >Hello</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

For future seekers.

```
<!-- This will show render as <div hidden>... -->
<div hidden={true}>Inner Content</div>

<!-- This will show render as <div>... -->
<div hidden={false}>Inner Content</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer :) It worked for me after an hour of trying alternatives.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't working for me. My component ends up with `hidden="false"` and then doesn't show. It only seems to happen to some components, possibly related to Shoelace.style

Comment: didn't work for me too

Comment: are you passing in a bool or a string

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:(to place custom attributes just add 'data-...')

```
function Welcome(props) {
 return window.innerWidth < 1024 ? <h1 data-attribute="hidden" >Hello</h1> : <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

Hope that helps.