# HTML "hidden" attribute is making page load forever when using with React

Tags: html, reactjs, hidden

I am trying to create a tab component with simple react state. But when using the
`hidden` 
attribute the page start loading forever. Even if I restart the project the problem appears again.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InventoryMain = () => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tabs">
        <span onClick={()=> setTabIndex(0)} className="tab tab-lifted" >Tab 1</span>
        <span onClick={()=> setTabIndex(1)} className="tab tab-lifted tab-active">Tab 2</span>
      </div>
      <div className="tab-contents">
        <div className="tab-1" hidden={tabIndex !== 0}>Tab1 </div>
        <div className="tab-2" hidden={tabIndex !== 1}>Tab2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InventoryMain;
```

I was expecting a simple tab and was watching this video.
[Simple React Tab video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNAhxstNz7s)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608085/placing-hidden-attribute-with-react-in-tag

Comment: Just changed the `tabIndex` for `useState`. @WOUNDEDStevenJones
And it is not react-specific it is available on HTML
[MDN: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)